# Error building AAB - Flutter (Android) - Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

Tags: java, android, flutter, keystore

I am trying to build an AAB for my flutter app. I generated the keystore using the following below command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/pc-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias pckey
```

I have a *key.properties* file, and I have referenced it using the provided code in the flutter docs. How can I solve this Java related issue?  My program throws the following exception

```
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.                     
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Failed to read key pckey from store "/Users/jrperfetto/pc-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
```

Comment: This solution solved my issue -- https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/5871#issuecomment-855597669

Comment: Mark this as "answered" pls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68773266/8164116

Answer (score 138):

I was getting the same error, I try this command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS
```

with extra attribute

```
-storetype JKS
```

it helps me to solve my problem and successfully create bundle.

The -storetype JKS tag is only required for Java 9 or newer. As of the Java 9 release, the keystore type defaults to PKS12.

Comment: It worked for me, too. one question, Is there any harm to using the JKS instead of the PKS12?

Comment: solved the problem but what about the warning to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard?

Comment: This one solved the issue!

Comment: Is this Windows?

Comment: This worked for me ,on mac please remember to check the java -version and avoid buildgradle 3.5.0

Comment: worked on M1 Mac, thanks.

Comment: What a champ! Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me.. in mac M1. Thanks

Answer (score 48):

It turns out i was generating my signing key using a different Java Version than my app was using to build the app. You can check this by running flutter doctor -v and seeing where the Java binary is located, and comparing it to when you run "which java".

The solution is to run your keygen command prefixed with the location of the Java bin found in the flutter doctor output like so:

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/pc-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias pckey
```

Comment: The same command fails because HmacPBESHA256 algorithm is not available in java 11 which is shipped with Android Studio. @Jason Does this happen to you?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i faced the same issue regardless of trying from terminal or running a build from Android Studio - ultimately the only way I could fix the problem was by prefixing my java location as mentioned in my followup

Comment: That's weird, can you check the java version shipped with Android studio?

/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --version

Comment: I did find a way to get it working is to use `genkeypair` rather than `-genkey`. 

I created an issue here: https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/5871

Comment: I did as you said, But I didn't know in which location keystone file is created. I executed this command in root folder to prevent permission issue. Can you tell me the location where keystore file is created?

Comment: @expectedAn I am using genkeypair and Java 16, but still I am getting error. What alternatives can I try?

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution resolved it

Comment: Solved the issue, thank you. For me, the path to keytool is : /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/keytool

Answer (score 15):

Note:
The keytool command might not be in your path—it’s part of Java, which is installed as part of Android Studio. For the concrete path, run flutter doctor -v and locate the path printed after ‘Java binary at:’. Then use that fully qualified path replacing java (at the end) with keytool. If your path includes space-separated names, such as Program Files, use platform-appropriate notation for the names. For example, on Mac/Linux use Program\ Files, and on Windows use "Program Files".
The -storetype JKS tag is only required for Java 9 or newer. As of the Java 9 release, the keystore type defaults to PKS12

**1- remove upload-keystore.jks**

```
a-  /android/app/upload-keystore.jks
b- /home/user/upload-keystore.jks
```

2- **Regenerate file :**

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS
```

3- copy file /home/user/**upload-keystore.jks** to android/app/

4- `flutter clean`

5- `Flutter build appbundle`

Comment: I have a MacOs M1 and this solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This work for me at Feb 2024.

Answer (score 15):

**If you haven't already created a keystore file:**

1. Mac:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS
```

2. Windows (change USER_NAME):

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore "c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks" -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

**If you have already created a keystore file before:**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "path/to/upload-keystore.jks" -destkeystore "path/to/new-upload-keystore.jks" -deststoretype JKS
```

Comment: This solution works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

**IF YOU CAN'T/DON'T WANT TO GENERATE NEW KEYS
.**

Generating new keys was not an option for me because our app is already in production and contacting google was such a hassle. As others have pointed out, the build fails because the app was signed with a java version higher than Java 11. But the HmacPBESHA256 algorithm is not available in java 11 which is shipped with Android Studio. That is, Android Studio is trying to build your app with Java 11.

So the solution for me was to get Android Studio to build the aab with my local java version, not java 11. To tell Android Studio which JDK version to use, in `gradle.properties`, I added:

`org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

After this, I was able to build my aab without any issues with the keys I already had.

Answer (score 4):

It solves me when I remove debug.keystore from the bellow directory.

/Users/tariqul/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: I have removed all the files related to Keystore, and worked.  Please remember to rebuild the key (SHA1 and SHA256) and update with firebase.

Answer (score 4):

Like Graciela, I am unable to recreate the certificate. However, I using Java 12+ in Android Studio isn't a good fix for me. Using an updated Java version works for deploying from my machine, but not from the CI server.

Instead, I exported and imported the certificate to change the signing algorithm.

Here are the steps I used:

Export the certificate to PKCS12 using Java v12+:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ./upload-keystore.jks -destkeystore ./pcstore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Using openssl, export the key as .pem

```
openssl pkcs12 -nodes -in pcstore.p12 -out keystore.pem
```

Create a new .p12 store using openssl

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in keystore.pem -out new-pcstore.p12 -name upload
```

Create a new jks store using the Android Studio version of Java (Java 11) by importing the .p12 store:

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ./new-pcstore.p12 -destkeystore ./new-upload-keystore.jks -deststoretype jks
```

Now the keystore works with Java 11 and it's using the same certificate I signed the app with before.

Comment: you are the best...
In addition, you can use the latest code directly from the terminal screen of android studio. Again, it will use the java version integrated into Android studio.
example;
`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore .../new-pcstore.p12 -destkeystore .../new-upload-keystore.jks -deststoretype jks`

Answer (score 2):

Add this in last of your command

*-storetype JKS*

Like,

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the way I solved the problem is the right way, and I don't know if others will solve it this way, but I think I would have solved it if I had done a lot of things.

I adapted JAVA_HOME to the form of the java binary that came up with `flutter doctor -v`  like this

```
% flutter doctor -v                            
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
.
.
.
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

and set `JAVA_HOME` to `.zshrc`

```
% cd ~
% vi .zshrc
```

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"
```

```
% echo $JAVA_HOME
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
```

and

```
% flutter clean
% flutter build appbundle
```

and that works

```
% flutter build appbundle

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                         4.1s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab (21.2MB).
```

Answer (score 1):

The @azhar-ali answer does not work for me on Ubuntu 2020.04. And I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70337364/5921933) that worked.

**Commands:**

```bash
keytool -genkey -v -keystore upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore upload-keystore.jks -destkeystore upload-keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12

openssl pkcs12 -nodes -in upload-keystore.p12 -out upload-keystore.pem

openssl pkcs12 -export -in upload-keystore.pem -out new-upload-keystore.p12 -name upload
```

(Using p12 key instead of jks key)

**key.properties:**

```
storeFile=/home/admin/Documents/Working/projects/new-upload-keystore.p12
```

**Result:**

```bash
flutter build appbundle

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                           2,422ms
✓ Built build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab (16.6MB).
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue yesterday. I deleted my old debug key, which is located at `/Users/<username>/.android/debug.keystore`. I think this is the simplest way to handle this problem for a Newbie like me.

P.S. Not sure about the "release" mode. This just works for "debug" mode.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me :)

```
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-16.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -genkey -v -keystore android/app/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem befor and i solve it when i change the JDK from 11 version to 16 version in windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I have used gradle 7.3 build tool to compile the source. it is worked without any problem.

First, download gradle from this link: https://gradle.org/releases/

Unzip it in your preferred location

Than run this command: `export PATH=$PATH:/gradle_bin_path`

This will add gradle binary for current terminal session only. If you want to add this path for permanent, you need to follow extra step:

first run this command to get what terminal you are using:

```
echo $SHELL
```

I am using zsh as shell, so if the output is /bin/zsh than run this following commands:

```
sudo -s
cd /users/username
ls
vim .zshrc
```

Before editing the .zshrc file, be sure to have a backup of this file

And than add following line to this file: `export PATH=$PATH:/gradle_bin_path`

Save and quit the editor.

Than run this command: `source .zshrc`

The path list now updated. Let's run this command:

```
gradle --version
```

It should show current gradle version.

Now, time to compile the app. lets cd to directory where your project is.

Then, run this command: `gradle clean`

Wait till gradle finish sync your project. once finish sync, run this command:

```
gradle build
```

Finally, you will be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very simple. Just delete your file mentioned in the error log.
For example in my case the path was shown below.

```
C:\Users\kattie\.android\debug.keystore.jks
```

Delete this debug.keystore.jks file and make sure you close android studio or OpenJDK process from task manager.

Comment: your solution works fine

Answer (score -1):

AS I lost my Keystore, and was unable to return it back, read google documentation about getting a new key.

Google: If you’ve lost your private upload key or it’s been compromised, you can create a new one, and then ask your account owner to contact support to reset the key. When contacting support, make sure your account owner attaches the upload_certificate.pem file.

I emailed google at the following link:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key

They sent me the following commands to re-generate keystore and certificate.pem:

Here’s how to generate and register a new upload key:

Follow the instructions in the Android Studio Help Center to generate a new key. It must be different from any previous keys. Alternatively, you can use the following command line to generate a new key:

**keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks**

This key must be a 2048 bit RSA key and have 25-year validity.
Export the certificate for that key to PEM format:

**keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks**

Reply to this email and attach the upload_certificate.pem file, after replying, they will send an email mentioning your key store will be updated after 2 days,

now you have a new key store, in order to generate a signed bundle keys, you must do the following:

1- Go to the android side in your flutter (2.8.1) project.
2- go to settings> Build, Execution ..> Gradle>
3- change gradle JDK to something between 16 and 11, **JDK 15 worked for me.

**note: if you don't have jdk, you can download it in same place Gradle JDK with jdk
download option.
note: you must build your signed app bundle within android only not inside flutter framework.**

Answer (score -1):

Command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS  -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

worked for me on my mac m1.

i was using java version 17 and everytime i try to build appbundle i would get error

> Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

To solve this i added

> -deststoretype JKS
> in keytool command and it worked for me .

Answer (score -3):

in `android` > `app` folder, open `build.gradle` and make sure to keep

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

and before building release bundle, change it to

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add screenshots to make your answer easy to understand.