# Flutter - Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the following error while building my flutter app. I am not getting any errors while testing the app on an emulator, and it's working fine. I don't know what's wrong with the building. I appreciate any help you can provide.

flutter version: v2.5.3 | devtools: v2.8.0

I am using this command to build the app:

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

**here is the error log:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
      > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/APP_NAME/main_files/source/wordpress_app/android/app/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
      > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/APP_NAME/main_files/source/wordpress_app/android/app/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
      > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/APP_NAME/main_files/source/wordpress_app/android/app/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          135.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is your java up to date? Is your upload key in the expected place? That's what I would check first.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the latest java version. And my upload-keystore.jks file is also in the expected place.

which is: /users/MY_USERNAME/upload-keystore.jks

Comment: Something is wrong with your key tough. How did you generate it? Is your key.properties correctly filled?

Comment: I generated it by using this command: 
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
..
(My app is working fine in the emulator—the only issue while building.)
And my key.properties also correctly filled.

Comment: The keys are used to sign your release APK, so that's why you are not getting erros when running in a debug environment. Maybe you'll find this page helpful (https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution:**

try this command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS
```

with extra attribute

```
-storetype JKS
```

note: The -storetype JKS tag is only required for Java 9 or newer. As of the Java 9 release, the keystore type defaults to PKS12.

ref: [Error building AAB - Flutter (Android) - Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631927/error-building-aab-flutter-android-integrity-check-failed-java-security-n)