# Specify Java JDK Version Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need some help here solving an issue similar to this one

[Error building AAB - Flutter (Android) - Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631927/error-building-aab-flutter-android-integrity-check-failed-java-security-n)

I cannot seem to specify the Java JDK version in my Android Studio. The option for Gradle projects is simply not there (see image below). Can someone please help me on how I can specify a specific version of Java within Android Studio (needs to be greater than 11).

[image]

Comment: Try specifying the path of your **.gradle** folder first.

Comment: Is this within the build.gradle or gradle.properties folder? I am new to building apps, so a little bit more context would really help me. Thanks!

Comment: No, for me it was in Users/**UserID**/. gradle. I am on Windows though so can't say where's that folder for you.

Comment: Once you find it, you need to paste the path that box with title "Gradle user home".