# Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio, dart, keystore

I have this error at the moment to make `flutter build appbundle`

this is the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Failed to read key sd from store "C:\flutter_project\cursin2\cursin-main\android\app\upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                              9,1s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS C:\flutter_project\cursin2\cursin-main>
```

[image]

i've tried all ways to fix it, but the error is still appearing.

my key.properties:

```
storePassword=ul109000
keyPassword=ul109000
keyAlias=sd
storeFile=C:/flutter_project/cursin2/cursin-main/android/app/upload-keystore.jks
```

Comment: i've tried: flutter clean, deleting keystore, retrying generate key...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only method that worked for me was:

1. `flutter clean`
2. edit the path I used in key properties.

For example:

```
 "./upload-keystore.jks"
```

to

```
"C:/key/myapp/upload-keystore.jks"
```

3. `flutter build appbundle`

Answer (score 5):

in android `app/ build.gradle`

inside `android` tag

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

storeFile path will be `./upload-keystore.jks`

and

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i implemented that. this error appeared:  52: The current scope already contains a variable of the name keystoreProperties
   @ line 52, column 9.
         def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
             ^

Comment: i've changed that names, but now this error appear: "A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade > Failed to read key sd from store "C:\flutter_project\cursin2\cursin-main\android\app\upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available"

Comment: for the last error you can check this out. seems to be issue with keystore file :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631927/error-building-aab-flutter-android-integrity-check-failed-java-security-n

Comment: Flutter documentation says to put this code BEFORE android block https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Answer (score 5):

In my case key.properties file was missing(you can find that in android/build.gradle). If you have cloned your repo from github and then try to create appbundle then this issue may arise.

Generate new key.properties or take previous key.properties file to create appbundle.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this:

```
debug {
    storeFile file(storeFile_)
    storePassword storePassword_
    keyAlias keyAlias_
    keyPassword keyPassword_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

in `android app/ build.gradle`

replace this

```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

with this

```
   buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
   }
```

**Second**

remove `upload-keystore.jks` in your generation path in my case (Ubuntu OS)
the path is `/home/user/upload-keystore.jks`

**Third**

genrate a new key with with extra attribute

```
-storetype JKS
```

for Linux

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS
```