# I can't build appbundle with error "Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'."

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-app-bundle

The error below occurs when I try "flutter build appbundle".

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

I made this project with flutter,
so I made the release key in android studio menu build -> "generate signed bundle(apk)" (to use it, i had opened android module in android studio)

and the below is my code.

1. app build.gradle
   [image: app build.gradle(1): I added that.]
   [image: app build.gradle(2): I added signingconfig and minified,shrink,...]
2. key.properties
   [image: here is my key.properties]
3. my project tree

[image: here is my project tree]

you can see myreleasekey.jks in android\app,
and key.properties in android.
so I don't know what is the cause ...
thank you.

Comment: sync build / rebuild project first and check build logs errors to fix issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780523/execution-failed-for-task-appsignreleasebundle)