# How to solve error on releasing app bundle in flutter as given below

Tags: android, flutter, android-app-signing, release-builds

I am a Flutter newbie,

I was trying to release the build of an app but I am getting the below error on entering the flutter command "flutter build appbundle" on my mac.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/drole/Desktop/snackbar/android/app/key.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
```

How to resolve the above error, surfed internet but I don't get a proper solution.

Comment: Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67632064/10210902

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me to come out of error.