# Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available (Flutter Build Failed)

Tags: java, android, flutter

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/alisolanki/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
```

What I've tried:

---

1. Tried changing the JDK

[image: Changing JDK]

---

2. Tried creating a new keystore file (Appbundle gets created, however as it is a new keystore file, it doesn't get accepted to Google Playstore)

---

I don't want to go through the hassle of making a support request to Google Playstore of changing my upload key as I have the keystore and the password for it as well.

Comment: Hi! have you found any solution am also having same problem

Comment: Hey yes I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71955263/11731185

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue by following this solution on stackoverflow: [Error building AAB - Flutter (Android) - Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631927/error-building-aab-flutter-android-integrity-check-failed-java-security-n)

I was getting the same error, I try this command

keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS
with extra attribute

-storetype JKS
it helps me to solve my problem and successfully create bundle.

The -storetype JKS tag is only required for Java 9 or newer. As of the Java 9 release, the keystore type defaults to PKS12.

Comment: Hey! I found the solution using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71955263/11731185