# flutter build apk --split-per-abi: Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'

Tags: flutter, dart, app-bundle, flutter-build, flutter-apk

i have been trying to build a flutter apk with this `flutter build apk --split-per-abi:` but i seem to be getting this error, i tried to do some refactoring and corrections from StackOverflow but the error seems to persist

```
192:party_app olamide$ flutter build apk --split-per-abi

 Building with sound null safety 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
      > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/olamide/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
      > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/olamide/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
      > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/olamide/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           35.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
192:party_app olamide$
```

Comment: what is your java version?

Comment: Please share your key.properties file where you have set path for keystore file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error building AAB - Flutter (Android) - Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631927/error-building-aab-flutter-android-integrity-check-failed-java-security-n)

Comment: you need to create keystore.jks file again. follow steps from this link https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app

Answer (score 0):

it might be from gradle or you didn't pub get

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).