# Flutter/Android Signing issue - App Bundle was not signed (no manifest)

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, keystore, signing

I'm presently attempting to sign a Flutter-Android app bundle so it can be updated on on the Play store. It compiles without issues, however when uploaded the store give me a `The Android App Bundle was not signed` error.

Firstly, before I run flutter build, I tun both flutter pub get and flutter clean, in that order. Secondly, using Android Studio to build/sign has the same issue.

The Gradle script appears to be working fine locally and it's picking up the keystore file as well as able to read the signing variables from the properties file:

```
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file("../keystore.jks")
                file("../key.properties").with { propFile ->
                    if (propFile.canRead()) {
                        def properties = new Properties()
                        properties.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

                        storePassword = properties['storePassword']
                        keyAlias = properties['keyAlias']
                        keyPassword = properties['keyPassword']
                    } else {
                        storePassword = System.getenv("STORE_PASSWORD")
                        keyAlias = System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
                        keyPassword = System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
                    }

                    v1SigningEnabled true
                    v2SigningEnabled true
                }
            }
        }
```

Running `keytool -list -v -keystore ./keystore.jks` appears to return a valid keystore (details below masked):

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: key
Creation date: 28 Jun 2022
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=XXXXXXXX, OU=XXXXXXXX, O=XXXXXXXX, L=XXXXXXXX, ST=XXXXXXXX, C=XXXXXXXX
Issuer: CN=XXXXXXXX, OU=XXXXXXXX, O=XXXXXXXX, L=XXXXXXXX, ST=XXXXXXXX, C=XXXXXXXX
Serial number: XXXXXXXX
Valid from: Mon Apr 13 09:36:39 CEST 2020 until: Fri Aug 30 09:36:39 CEST 2047
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
         SHA256: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 0A 52 43 47 F1 16 86 8A   1B 3E 79 6D 6A BD 54 7E  .RCG.....>ymj.T.
0010: 67 8F 66 2B                                        g.f+
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************
```

Yet when I run `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app-release.aab`, after running the build it returns the following:

```
  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore

no manifest.
```

So, from what I can see I have valid credentials, a valid keystore and am doing a build correctly, however the signing appears to fail due to a problem with the, I presume, JAR manifest. I suspect either I'm missing a forehead-slapping mistake or there may be an issue specific to one of the frameworks in use (so it may not be specific to Flutter or even Android).

Anyone come across this, or can spot something I cannot or otherwise suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

THis works for me
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14\bin\keytool" -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass an
droid -keypass android

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14\bin\keytool** is the path of the keytool

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to solve this myself three days ago, but marcos' response does indirectly address the solution I thought it worth giving a broader answer for anyone else who comes across this issue, in the future.

The problem arises as there are numerous working parts to the process of signing an app, from the keytool, Gradle, Android command tools and, at least in this case, Flutter. If any of these is out of sync it's not going to work.

In my particular case it was a question of two different versions of Java that were in use. Flutter was using a version of Open JDK, while an Oracle version happened to be referenced in my PATH and thus this was what was being called when I accessed the keytool. So whenever creating or updating a keystore, it would use a different and thus incompatible keytool.

To discover what version of Java Flutter is using call `flutter doctor -v` and insure you're using the same version (marcos' response was broadly correct, but it wouldn't have worked for me as it was installed in another directory). To find what version of Java is currently in your PATH, you can reference `java -version`.

After this I had a second issue as I was using an existing, keystore, that had to be updated. For this I followed the solution that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631927/error-building-aab-flutter-android-integrity-check-failed-java-security-n). Hope all this helps someone else in the future.