# React-native fails to sign release build

Tags: android, react-native

Hello i recently got this error while running `npx react-native run-android --variant=release --no-jetifier`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key my-key from store "/Users/ad8kunle/Documents/react-native-projects/mvmarket/android/app/my-upload-key.keystore": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
```

It used to work fine, not sure what went wrong. Debug version runs fine.

GRADLE 7.3.3

REACT - NATIVE 8.6.0

Comment: Run `./gradlew signingReport` in your android folder what's wrong in your keystone file.

Comment: @RohitAggarwal Thanks for your respsonse. just ran it, it printed out a couple of things. this is the only one that has error - `Variant: release
Config: release
Store: /Users/ad8kunle/Documents/react-native-projects/mvmarket/android/app/mvmarket-upload-key.keystore
Alias: mvmarket-key
Error: Failed to read key mvmarket-key from store "/Users/ad8kunle/Documents/react-native-projects/mvmarket/android/app/mvmarket-upload-key.keystore": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available`

Comment: i generated new file. still didn't work @RohitAggarwal

Comment: Finally, this answer fixed it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69518880/19399679