# Flutter Issue: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

After spending so much time trying to fix flutter errors this tough one occurred:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\Home\.android\debug.keystore": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

How to solve this?

I searched everywhere but could not find a helpful solution.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631927/error-building-aab-flutter-android-integrity-check-failed-java-security-n

Comment: you have to add/update keystore.properties file.